# windows 7 - no longer able to tab between fields in QB

Tags: windows-7

There must have been an update installed without me knowing about it.

Today for the first time ever, pushing <kbd>TAB</kbd> to go between fields in Quickbooks no longer works - it brings up a totally new screen that shows the different sites I have open in IE.  I hate it - I've always tabbed my way around QB.  Is there someplace to turn this off?

Comment: Have you tried a reboot? how about mashing the ctrl, alt and shift keys a couple times?

Comment: Thanks - rebooted and it's back to normal.  Just weird though.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound weird, but there might be a software and/or hardware glitch causing this.  I've seen issues like this fixed by simply pressing the Escape key several times.  I've also seen things like this happen when using Synergy (http://synergy-foss.org/) and it is easily fixed by restarting the service.

Comment: Thanks - the reboot worked but if it happens again I'll try the Escape key first.